# Display one array value according to other array

Tags: android, arrays

I have created to arrays.One is for all the states(Full Form) in USA and other is the all short form of the states in USA.I have dispayed the states(Full form) in a spinner.Now what i have to do is display the state in short form according to which the user selects in the spinner.How can i achieve it.

Comment: Post your code what you have tried.

Comment: Get index of selected item of spinner and use this index to get value from other array...

Comment: how to do it @Haresh pls can u explain it??

Comment: have you done any code for this then plz post ?

Comment: Load the list(whatever you need short or full) in the adapter depend upon your situation from where you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use mapping i.e in both the arrays the elements should be mapped. Let me give you an example.

```
    String[] fullForm = { Alabama,  California,  Florida,   Illinois};
    String[] shortForm = {AL, CA, FL, IL};

    ArrayAdapter<String> ad = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,fullForm );

spinner.setAdapter(ad);

spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int position, long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " You selected " + fullForm[position] + "\n Short form is : " + shortForm[position], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// try this way,hope this will help you...

**activity_main.xml**

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center">

     <Spinner
         android:id="@+id/spnState"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>

**MainActivity.java**

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Spinner spnState;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle paramBundle) {
        super.onCreate(paramBundle);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        spnState = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spnState);
        String[] stateFullNameArray = new String[]{"statefullname1","statefullname2","statefullname3","statefullname4","statefullname5"};
        final String[] stateShortNameArray = new String[]{"stateshortname1","stateshortname2","stateshortname3","stateshortname4","stateshortname5"};

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,stateFullNameArray);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spnState.setAdapter(adapter);

        spnState.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,stateShortNameArray[position],Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });
    }


}
```